# Duda: Incremento de variable en Java

Tags: java, hilos, socket

Tengo un jFrame(server) que al presionar su boton hace lo siguiente y envia al hilo1...

```
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(9999);

        Hilo1 hilo = new Hilo1(ss,jLabel1,jLabel2,i);
        hilo.setDaemon(true);
        hilo.start();

        // System.out.println(i);
        //s = ss.accept();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente conectado correctamente ");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(estacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Depués, en el hilo 1 tengo un while que acepta las conexiones de los clientes de esta forma y envía al Hilo2, lo que quiero con esto es que la variable "i" incremente mediante haya conexiones de clientes...

```
public void run(){  

    while(i<3 && i>=0){

        try {
            sock = ss.accept();
            i++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente"+i+ "conectado correctamente ");
            System.out.println("cliente"+i+"conectado");

            if(i==1){
                j1.setText("ocupado");
            }

            if(i==2){
                j2.setText("ocupado");
            }

            Hilo2 hilo2 = new Hilo2(i,sock);
            hilo2.setDaemon(true);
            hilo2.start();

            //prueba.entero(i);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Hilo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    //
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay espacio");
}
```

En el Hilo2 quiero que la variable "i" decremente cuando se pulse el boton del jFrame2 que lo que simula es que el cliente se fue y queda un lugar disponible para que se conecte otro cliente...

Boton salir del JFrame2(cliente):

```
try {
        salida = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        salida.writeUTF("salir");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Carro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Hilo2:

```
  public void run(){
      try {
          entrada = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
          msg = entrada.readUTF();

          if(msg.equals("salir")){ 
              i--;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "un carro se fue "+i);
              prub = new Estacionamiento();
              prub.entero(i);
          }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Hilo2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
```

El problema es que no decrementa la `i` cada que doy salir, todo lo demás funciona bien. El objetivo de esto es simular mediante *sockets* un ESTACIONAMIENTO que cuando llega un carro (cliente) al estacionamiento (servidor) se vayan llenando los lugares disponibles, en este caso 2, y cuando se vayan vuelva a haber lugares disponibles y el estacionamiento acepte carros de nuevo.

Comment: Hablas de cliente y servidor, lo que me lleva a pensar que estamos hablando de una aplicación distribuida, pero también tu código muestra una variable que supuestamente estás compartiendo entre el cliente y el servidor, lo cual no es posible si realmente tu aplicación es distribuida (Cliente-Servidor).

Comment: Hago la conexión cliente-servidor en local host, lo que necesito es que el servidor solo permita que se conecten 3 clientes, una vez conectados los 3 clientes no permita mas conexiones hasta que uno de ellos se desconecte y de esta forma permita conectar otro mas solo por que uno ya se desconecto. Es lo que queria simular con el contador.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es que ambos threads se comuniquen entre si. Podrías pasar la referencia del `Hilo1` al crear instancias de `Hilo2`, de manera que este ultimo le informe al primero que ha finalizado.

Por ejemplo, en `Hilo2`:

```
    public Hilo2(int i, Socket sock, Hilo1 hilo1) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = sock;
        this.hilo1 = hilo1;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String msg = entrada.readUTF();

            if (msg.equals("salir")) {
                hilo1.liberarEstacionamiento();
                i--;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "un carro se fue " + i);
                prub = new Estacionamiento();
                prub.entero(i);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Hilo2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Y en `Hilo1`:

```
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (i < 3 && i >= 0) {
                try {
                    Socket sock = ss.accept();
                    int c = i + 1;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente" + c + "conectado correctamente ");
                    System.out.println("cliente" + c + "conectado");

                    if (c == 1) {
                        j1.setText("ocupado");
                    }

                    if (c == 2) {
                        j2.setText("ocupado");
                    }

                    Hilo2 hilo2 = new Hilo2(c, sock, this);
                    hilo2.setDaemon(true);
                    hilo2.start();

                    utilizarEstacionamiento();
                    //prueba.entero(i);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Hilo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void utilizarEstacionamiento() {
        ++i;

        while (i >= 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay espacio");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Hilo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void liberarEstacionamiento() {
        --i;
        notifyAll();
    }
```

La idea de lo anterior, es que para aumentar o decrementar la variable `i` se haga de forma sincronizada obteniendo el *lock* del mismo *thread*.

Si es que se aumenta fuera del rango admitido de clientes, entonces el *thread* que escucha por mas clientes queda esperando hasta que se liberen mas espacios.

Al liberarse un espacio, se notifica a todos los *threads* esperando para verifiquen sus condiciones.